Who are the Dipshits?
Uptop: It was Rachel in the pub. Thanks all.

Who are the Dipshits?

Why is this on the front page?

Am I considered one of them? The link leads to "Welcome, Paul. We’re excited to have you..."




I have it. It was Sergeant XXXXXXX when I went to powder my face. I answer a lot of questions from the pub. It's best if we forget this episode, otherwise she'll rip my head off, literally :-( Question closed.

don't take too much powder! :)

Good question - who are the Dipshits? :D
According to what I can see in our system, it looks like you created a Team on Stack Overflow on January 19th and called it "Dipshits". You can click on the link in the sidebar to visit the Team. If you didn't intend to create the Team or you'd like to delete it (so that it no longer appears in your sidebar), you should be able to cancel it by visiting the admin panels within the Team and it will be deleted after 60 days.
If you don't remember doing this - is there a possibility that someone accessed your account without your knowledge (e.g. left your account logged in on a shared device)?

Jan 19th of this year?

I can't see the creation date - I had to ask someone on the Customer Support side for help with that and all they said was "January 19th". If it wasn't this year, then it's been in the sidebar for quite a while and you just now noticed. :)
